# Which tools to use to backup SQL servers to csv files and delete?

Tags: backup, csv, database, sql-server

I need an app which can do the following tasks:

1. Log in into an SQL database (Microsoft, Oracle, etc.)
2. Find the oldest data in some tables (can do with query; the tables have a "datetime" field)
3. Save these data into a csv file
4. Delete these data from database
5. Repeat aumatically after X minutes

I searched for [backup apps](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-database-backup-tools/) and couldn't find anyone which would do these steps. They normally simply do scheduled backups of the entire database or from data inserted since the last backup and I want something specific for just some tables. Moreover they usually don't erase the data and I need that to be done. Preference for freeware.

Comment: Previously I would have done this with Powershell. Have you considered doing this with Microsoft Flow?

Comment: @pholcroft well I was thinking about using an existing solution in case there were any. After all this seems a relativaly basic procedure. But if I need to do it myself, I'ld prefer to code a windows service instead.

Comment: I think powershell, agent jobs, microsoft flow are the existing solutions for this. You can script what should happen and set it to repeat regularly. I have done something very similar to this using a Windows Service which worked great, but with hindsight was overkill (I did it this way as I was experienced in C# / Windows Services and SQL Connections. If I were you I'd start with trying a SQL Agent Job.